# queries all in one seo pack 2.1.4 by michael torbert

Tags: wordpress

For seo I have make meta-description using all in one seo pack 2.1.4, but i can't able to see the description in view source.

Only half of the description can see.

How can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The meta-description in one seo pack 2.1.4 only accept the limit number of characters. Let limit the number of characters in your description string to less than 156 characters to get it show up

Comment: ok but i have deactivated that plugin and install 2.0.4 also same issue

Comment: Maybe you can try Wordpress SEO by Yoast, it detect the situation better.